# How to get the reference to the Movie player controller from the video tag in the webview?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I've a view controller which presents a webview, with a video tag, when the video begins to play, it plays in the full screen mode in the native iOS video player.
How can I get the reference to the Movie player controller, which is being presented by the webview in the code ?
Once, I get the reference I need to add a button to the player via code.